# Importrange with query and reorder some of the columns on import Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I have a sheet with 52 columns from A to AZ.  I am importing these with Importrange and query to a different file.

I want to move Column X  to the first column on the import

Is this possible to do `without` listing the order of `all` 52 columns in the query?

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  QUERY(
    {
      TRIM(IFERROR(IMPORTRANGE("1Qe####","Sheet1!A2:AZ"&counta(importrange("1Qe###","Sheet1!A2:AZ")))))
    },
    "select col24, col1,...,col52",1
  )
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one approach and change it accordingly:

`=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("SPREADSHEET ID","Sheet1!A2:AZ"),"Select Col29"&", "&SUBSTITUTE(JOIN(", ",INDEX("Col"&SEQUENCE(52))),", Col29",""))`

Comment: how could I exclude only Col1, but then return all the rest using SEQUENCE. This seems like such a time-saver, from having to list alllll the columns I need to return.

Comment: [sequence function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244?hl=en) has a start parameter and you could give it as `2`